# Spring MVC dispatcher not working. HTTP 404

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, http-status-code-404

I've seen a lot of similar thread but none solves my 'problem?'. Please tell me what I missed? When i try to go to http://localhost:8080/helloworld.html i get "HTTP Status 404".

> HelloWorldController.java

```
   @Controller
    public class HelloWorldController {

   @RequestMapping(value="/helloworld.html")
    public ModelAndView helloWorld() {

        return new ModelAndView("HelloWorldPage"); }
     }
```

> web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

</web-app>
```

> dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
   <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.site.controller"/>

    <bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
     <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
     <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

    </beans>
```

file structure:
[https://s18.postimg.org/4j699vn6x/stack.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IK2D.png)

> pom.xml

```
...
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
...
```

Comment: which server you are using ?

Comment: I tested this code at Tomcat,JBoss and always I getting the same error.

Comment: There is no problem with `@RequestMapping(value="/helloworld.html")`. Is there `HelloWorldPage.jsp` under `/WEB-INF/pages/` ?

Comment: Yes, problem was the server configuration, it doesn't load libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you should configure your application:

**On your web.xml you should confifure the dispatcher servlet like this:**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>


<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**The controller should look like this:**

```
@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {

   @RequestMapping(value="/")
   public ModelAndView helloWorld() {

        return new ModelAndView("HelloWorldPage"); }
   }
```

**Now, according to your image I'm guessing that your tomcat context is `untitled7` so after tomcat is up & running try to hit the next URL:**

http://localhost:8080/untitled7

Comment: can you post your stack trace with your exception? after the change.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Problem was the server configuration, it doesn't load libraries.